# Syntax highlighting Fortran code in IPython notebook

Tags: fortran, syntax-highlighting, jupyter-notebook

I want to include some Fortran code in my IPython notebook. How do I get the code snippet to be syntax highlighted ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to do this using the  [pygments_magic extension](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/gist/jiffyclub/5385520).

It uses [pygmentize](http://pygments.org/demo/852892/) which supports fortran syntax highlighting.

If you want to execute Fortran code you could use [fortran-magic](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/fortran-magic)

Comment: Thank you. I was able to include my Fortran snippet successfully with syntax highlighting.